# Laravel save() - inserting the data instead update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Want to updating the data using laravel. I make a function inside the model and using that method inside the controller but when calling the method its inserting the data with new id.function as following .

```
public function edit_client($req,$id) { 
    $client = new client(); 
    $client->find($id); 
    $client->name = $req->name; 
    $client->address = $req->address; 
    $client->email = $req->email; 
    $client->phone = $req->phone; 
    $client->gender = $req->gender; 
    $client->department = $req->department; 
    $client->update();}
```

Comment: Yes, because of `$client = new client();`.. remove or comment this line and try again.

Comment: Inserting new record.

Comment: Yes `save()` will insert new record.

Comment: with $client->update(); no changes and with $client->save(); inserting new record

Comment: I want to update record not insertion.

Comment: `client` is your model name?

Comment: `Client::where('id', $id)->update(['column' => 'value', 'anotherColumn' => 'value'])`

Comment: will it update the updated_at automatically ?

Comment: Yes `updated_at` will be updated automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example:

```
    $obj= Client::where('id', $id)->update([
        'name' = $req->name,
        'address' = $req->address,
        'email' = $req->email,
        'phone' = $req->phone,
        'gender' = $req->gender,
        'department' = $req->department
    ]);
```

Comment: Seriously? You checked my answer as best answer, in a day one of your friends copy-pasted my code without any changes and you took it away and checked his answer. Nice behavior.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this instead:

```
public function edit_client($req,$id) { 
    $client = Client::find($id); 
    $client->name = $req->name; 
    $client->address = $req->address; 
    $client->email = $req->email; 
    $client->phone = $req->phone; 
    $client->gender = $req->gender; 
    $client->department = $req->department; 
    $client->save();
}
```

Or use `update()` method:

```
public function edit_client($req,$id) { 
    $client = Client::where('id', $id)->update([
        'name' = $req->name,
        'address' = $req->address,
        'email' = $req->email,
        'phone' = $req->phone,
        'gender' = $req->gender,
        'department' = $req->department
    ]);
}
```

If you'll decide to use `update()` method, do not forget to add [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) array.

Comment: Thanks its working. one question ? function is in same model so may i use $this instead $client.

Comment: If you'll decide to use this code in the model, then yes you should use it like this: `return $this->where('id', $id)->update(....);`

Comment: may i use $this->save(); i mean without creating instance.

Comment: You can do this in model: `$client = $this->find($id); $client->email = 'newemail@email.com'; $client->save();`

Comment: ok  thanks, Will you please explain why i cant use $this-
>find; $this->email = 'newemail@email.com'; $this->save(); whats the reason?